# Is it okay to tell my coworkers I am leaving just one day before I quit?

Tags: resignation

I work as the only designer at a company.
I submitted my one month notice period, but I kept postponing telling my coworkers. Also my boss didn't do it.
I am one day away from leaving, is it too weird to send them an email one day before I quit?

Comment: your boss did not address this with you before?

Comment: Maybe a chat with the ones you worked closest would be fine even on the last day, sending bulk mails to everyone in the company (obviously depending on the size of the company) would just clog up their inbox and be ignored.. Do you have an internal system such as sharepoint where new arrivals and recent departures are shared across the company?

Comment: Thinking about those that you are working closely with. Yes it is weird to inform them one day before your last day. It's even more weird to inform them on your last day. Can you give a reason why you kept that secret for a month?

Comment: Have you confirmed with your manager that they are aware you are leaving?  Has there been any hand-off of responsibilities or training a replacement?

Comment: Is this a remote job? There is something you're not telling us. If you don't tell us what led up to this, then we can't really offer good advice.

Comment: Technically, this is your supervisor's issue, not your.  Is it odd though?  yes...

Answer (score 18):

It's going to seem somewhat odd.

But less odd than just vanishing and not turning up tomorrow; whatever you do is going to be somewhat odd at this stage, that's the hole you've dug for yourself.

Answer (score 4):

> I am one day away from leaving, is it too weird to send them an email
> one day before I quit?

It will certainly be odd. But it's less "weird" than just disappearing without telling anyone.

Perhaps offer to meet folks for dinner or a drink after work hours.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it okay to tell my coworkers I am leaving just one day before I quit?

It would be OK to do so unless your company has a policy against that.

In general, I think most (if not all) companies allow the leaving employees to let their coworkers know that or to send a general ***goodbye*** email to your team.

If your company does not allow that, then it should be noted in the employee handbook or HR policy.

Comment: Even if it's against company policy, what could the possibly do? Fire the OP?

Comment: Burn bridges!  Always be respectful of the management team at the company EVEN if you are leaving.  It's their problem, not the OP's!